# phoenix framework how to render object as json in a template

Tags: phoenix-framework

I would like to render an object as JSON within a template.  I have tried:

```
<pre><%= @myobj %></pre>
```

but I get an error

```
protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for %Ecto.Changeset{...
```

is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phoenix uses the Poison library for JSON encoding/decoding. Therefore you can call `Poison.encode!(@myobj)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= text_input f, :field, data: [datakey: Poison.encode!(%{id: 123})] %>
```

Comment: Hi radzserg; your code might be correct, but it would be a better answer with some context; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: Well docs are wide accessible https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#__struct__/0 but do not provide an answer for this question. As for context it's clear from the answer - user wants to render json inside .eex template.